# Pass Array to Function That Returns the Minimum Value in the Array

Tags: excel, vba

Note: 1) I don't want to use Application.Worksheetfunction.Min; 2) I want to reject array elements that are not vbDouble; 3) I do not know ahead of time how many elements are in the passed array

```
Public Function getArrayMin(ByRef passedArray() As Double) As Double
'return min of valid numbers in an array

Dim element As Variant
Dim i As Integer

getArrayMin = 1E+25

i = 0
For Each element In passedArray
    If VarType(element) = vbDouble Then
        i = i + 1
        If element < passedArray(i) Then
            getArrayMin = passedArray(i)
        End If
    End If
Next

End Function
```

JNevill's edited version, which still does not work:

```
Function getArrayMin(passedArray() As Double) As Double
Dim minVal As Double
Dim element As Variant

minVal = 1E+25

For Each element In passedArray
    If element < minVal Or element = passedArray(0) Then
        minVal = element
    End If
Next element

getArrayMin = minVal
End Function
```

Comment: You didn't return anything. Also, while `cell` is technically fine, try something like `element` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
Public Function getArrayMin(passedRange As range) As Double
'return min of valid numbers in an array

Dim myarray() As Variant
Dim cell As Variant
Dim i As Integer

myarray = passedRange.value

getArrayMin = 1E+25

For Each cell In passedRange
    If VarType(cell) = vbDouble Then
        If getArrayMin > cell Then
            getArrayMin = cell
        End If
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
For Each element In passedArray
    If VarType(element) = vbDouble Then
        i = i + 1
        If cell < passedArray(i) Then
            passedArray(i) = element
        End If
    End If
Next
```

This seems odd. You are looping through elements in the array, testing it to see if the next element is larger, and if the next element is larger you set the next element to the current element. Then you do it again.

So... after this runs, the "min" should theoretically be in `passedArray(ubound(passedArray))`.

I guess that will work, but it feels odd because it blows away your array and fills it with intermediate garbage except for the first and last elements.

The gotcha is that you don't have a next element once you hit the uBound of your array. That last element is going to cause problems, but you don't really need to analyze it since it will contain the min already. To get around the error this will cause you could change that `if` statement to be:

```
 If VarType(element) = vbDouble and i < uBound(passedArray) Then
```

At the end of your function just stick in the following so that your function returns a value.

```
 getArrayMin=passedArray(uBound(passedArray)).
```

You could also not have it return anything since you used `byRef`, but it means after you call this function, you would need to get the last element, so it would look like:

```
getArrayMin(myArray)
minOFArray=myArray(Ubound(myArray))
```

Just keep in mind that you are using `byRef` and that your original array that you pass to the function is going to be blown away by the function rewriting all the elements. Personally, I would use byVal and insure that the function returns a min.

---

As a total rewrite, I would do something like this instead:

```
Function getArrayMin(passedArray AS Double) as Double
    Dim minVal as double
    Dim element as variant

    For each element in passedArray
        if element < minVal or element = passedArray(0) Then minVal = element
    Next element

    getArrayMin = minVal
End Function
```

It's more concise and there is no monkeying around with your array. I didn't check for a double since the `passedarray` parameter is already declared as a double. It shouldn't allow a string or some other element through.

---

Lastly, the rewrite above will give you a jumping off point if your logic needs to get more complicated. But the easiest way to do what your doing would be to just use Application.Min():

```
getArrayMin = Application.Min(passedArray)
```

Comment: I'm a moron. Please see revised code above. However, my revision still does not work.

Comment: Your revision isn't working because you are grabbing the next element, but your comparison says "If my current element is LESS THAN my next element THEN... my next elemen is the minElement??" That doesn't work out.  Check out the total rewrite at the bottom of my answer. It's more concise and should give a cleaner start to work off of.

Comment: still doesn't work. Your code did not compile until I added () in the function heading. I also initialized minVal. Still no luck. Note: My function call is =getArrayMin("I26:I28")  where I26:I28 contain doubles. Also note: arrays must always be passed byRef, which is the default if not specified.